# array combine by array key in php?

Tags: php

**is there a good function that can combine array by key ? ( in this example is pid )**

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      'product' => string 'a product pid 3' (length=9)
      'name' => string 'adamramadhan' (length=12)
      'pid' => string '3' (length=1)
      'timecreate' => string '2011-02-26 13:30:07' (length=19)
  1 => 
    array
      'product' => string 'a product pid 4' (length=8)
      'name' => string 'adamramadhan' (length=12)
      'pid' => string '4' (length=1)
      'timecreate' => string '2011-02-26 13:30:54' (length=19)
```

and

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      'pid' => string '3' (length=1)
      'comment' => string 'a comment on pid 3' (length=8)
  1 => 
    array
      'pid' => string '4' (length=1)
      'comment' => string 'a comment on pid 4' (length=8)
  2 => 
    array
      'pid' => string '3' (length=1)
      'comment' => string 'a comment on pid 3' (length=5)
  3 => 
    array
      'pid' => string '4' (length=1)
      'comment' => string 'a comment on pid 4' (length=5)
  4 => 
    array
      'pid' => string '3' (length=1)
      'comment' => string 'a comment on pid 3' (length=7)
  5 => 
    array
      'pid' => string '4' (length=1)
      'comment' => string 'a comment on pid 4' (length=7)
  6 => 
    array
      'pid' => string '3' (length=1)
      'comment' => string 'a comment on pid 3' (length=18)
  7 => 
    array
      'pid' => string '4' (length=1)
      'comment' => string 'a comment on pid 4' (length=18)
```

to something like

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      'product' => string 'a product pid 3' (length=9)
      'name' => string 'adamramadhan' (length=12)
      'pid' => string '3' (length=1)
      'timecreate' => string '2011-02-26 13:30:07' (length=19)
      'comments' => array 
        0 => 
          array
            'pid' => string '3' (length=1)
            'comment' => string 'a comment on pid 3' (length=8)
        2 => 
          array
            'pid' => string '3' (length=1)
            'comment' => string 'a comment on pid 3' (length=5)
        4 => 
          array
            'pid' => string '3' (length=1)
            'comment' => string 'a comment on pid 3' (length=7)
        6 => 
          array
            'pid' => string '3' (length=1)
            'comment' => string 'a comment on pid 3' (length=18)
  1 => 
    array
      'product' => string 'a product pid 4' (length=8)
      'name' => string 'adamramadhan' (length=12)
      'pid' => string '4' (length=1)
      'timecreate' => string '2011-02-26 13:30:54' (length=19)
      'comments' => array 
        1 => 
          array
            'pid' => string '4' (length=1)
            'comment' => string 'a comment on pid 4' (length=8)
        3 => 
          array
            'pid' => string '4' (length=1)
            'comment' => string 'a comment on pid 4' (length=5)
        5 => 
          array
            'pid' => string '4' (length=1)
            'comment' => string 'a comment on pid 4' (length=7)
        7 => 
          array
            'pid' => string '4' (length=1)
            'comment' => string 'a comment on pid 4' (length=18)
```

or with no pid on each product comments array ( nested on products array ) ?

thanks for looking in.

Adam Ramadhan

Comment: You do not care about the integer first key?

Comment: sorry i dont get which one is the int first key , the first key on products array ?

Comment: Does not mater, the 0-1 in the first array and the 0-7 in the second array. But check my solution anyway :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// Use pid as key
foreach ($arr1 as $key => $value) {
    $arr1_new[$value['pid']] = $value;
}

// Move comments into $arr1_new
foreach($arr2 as $key => $value) {
    $arr2_new[$value['pid']]['comments'][] = $value['comment'];
    // $arr2_new[$value['pid']]['comments'][] = $value; // if you really need all information here...
}

var_dump($arr2_new);
```

Comment: What does the result look like? How "mixed"?

Comment: My fault, changed `$arr1_new` into `$arr2_new` in the second foreach, It should work now.

Comment: thank you powtac, you save me alot of my time, its 6 hours already figuring this thing out. testing one by one php array function. may god repay you in someway someday :D

Comment: No prob Adam, once everybody has to learn how to deal with multidimensional arrays ;)